# FileUpload.Has File always return false

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

Here is my code, i didn't use updatepanel. but fileupload.hasfile always return false though file is selected.

```
 <asp:FileUpload ID="childPictureUpload" runat="server" CssClass="form-    control" />

    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btndeChildPictureUpload" Text="Upload Logo" Visible="false" OnClick="btndeChildPictureUpload_Click" class="btn btn-primary" />
```

code behind:

```
            if (childPictureUpload.HasFile)
            {
                allfeatureDetail.ImageUrl = ImageUpload(childPictureUpload, "~/All Photos/AllFeatureDetails/").ToString();
            }
```

Comment: Any chance you could show the code behind?

Comment: @ourmandave could you please check my code-behind?

Answer (score 0):

It should work. I have copied your asp code(just removed the cssClass as I haven't defined any). Here is the Backend logic for ImageUpload function.

```
protected void btndeChildPictureUpload_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (childPictureUpload.HasFile) {
     string fileName = Path.GetFileName(childPictureUpload.FileName);
     childPictureUpload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(fileName));
     Image1.ImageUrl = fileName;
  }   
}
```